# defied expectations to become even stronger

Tags: phrase-meaning

The Wall Street Journal tweeted

At 24, the most powerful gymnast in history has **defied expectations to become even stronger**—after surviving abuse, enduring a family ordeal and overcoming her own doubts.

I don't understand the phrase "defied expectations to become even stronger" - which appears to me to have opposite meanings: One refers to "unexpectedly became stronger/got a surprising success" and the other refers to "became a loser/made the people disappointed." Which is correct?

Comment: People thought she would weaken but she became stronger, thus defying their expectations.

Comment: You're looking for English grammar lessons in all the wrong places, I'm afraid. It's a tweet. Certain adjustments are made due to character limits.

Comment: To 'defy expectations' doesn't mean to disappoint people, it means to do the opposite of what people expected - usually, to do much better than expected.

Comment: Thank you. The problem in understanding probably derived from the idea that I thought "expectation" was a good/positive, rather than bad/negative, word, so the outcome to "defy expectations" would be disappointing.